# Sql Query in MSACCESS 2007 - Trying to group by

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I am trying to group my results together based on Room numbers. This query gives the results I'm after but I would like to order the results.

Current Results from the report

```
Date        Room Boxes Kilos
12/12/2013   01   153  487.79
12/12/2013   02    64  254.11
12/12/2013   03   101  163.23 Etc etc
```

I have up to 12 rooms which they are roughly grouped for team purposes. So I would like to have on the report the rooms in the following order:-

```
3
6
8
2
9
12
4
10
11
1
5
7
```

At the moment they come out

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

Here is the Sql used to extract the data.

```
SELECT Pickerid AS Id, Pickername AS Name, ROUND(SUM(totalweighta),2) AS TotalWeight, SUM(totalweighta)/SUM(pickerhours) AS HourlyRate, sum(boxcount) AS Boxes, sum(AvgBox) AS AvgBoxWeight, SUM(pickerhours) AS Hours
FROM (SELECT pickerid,currentdate,pickerhours,pickername,ROUND(SUM(currentweight),2) AS totalweighta, count(*) AS BoxCount, avg(currentweight) as AvgBox, SUM(pickerhours) AS Pickerhoursa
FROM mergeddatabase
GROUP BY pickerid,currentdate,pickerhours,pickername)  AS [%$##@_Alias]
WHERE ((currentdate between [Enter first date:] AND [Enter last date:]) and (pickerhours > 0.1) and (pickerid <> 36) and (pickerid <> 67))
GROUP BY pickerid, pickername
ORDER BY 4 DESC;
```

Thanks in advance..
Mark

Comment: What is it being grouped by? Or maybe I should ask, why should it come up 'Room 3, 6, 8....'

Comment: I am so sorry team... I have given you a bum steer.. I pasted the wrong query... Here is the correct query.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it in that specific order and that order is not going to change frequently then you would create a new table with the order that you need. Then you would write a new query that uses your existing query as a source as well as your new table. Then you would join the two tables as part of that query and it should give you the results in that desired order.